# Wakeonlan doesnt work when I send it from router

Tags: linux, linux-networking, wake-on-lan

I have a network connected to internet via linux box that does routing. Router has two interfaces:

- eth1: connection to internet
- eth2: lan

In lan I have two machines:

- workstation
- target

All machines work under Debian Linux.

I try to start "target" host remotely using wakeonlan tool.

When I do, on workstation:

```
sudo wakeonlan 94:c6:91:1b:3d:2a
```

after a minute or so, target host is up.

But when I do the same thing on router - target doesn't start.

I guess that it has to do with interfaces, but wakeonlan doesn't let me specify interface to send magic packet to.

Is there any way to diagnose it and potentially fix?

On router there is firewall installed (using iptables), but I don't really see any rules that would prohibit wakeonlan.

Comment: Solved it by using etherwake, as it has -I argument to provide interface name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are correct with the assumption that the interface used is the problem.

Maybe you can force the interface to use by giving a more limited broadcast address. Asssuming your LAN network is `192.168.10.0/24`, try

```
sudo wakeonlan -i 192.168.10.255 <mac address>
```

(this is untested, just something to try).

If that does not work: `etherwake` let you specify the interface with the `-i` switch and is available in the Debian repos.

Comment: Tried, didn't help :(

Comment: Solved it by using etherwake, as it has -I argument to provide interface name.